# Android : How to draw a lines with some time delay?

Tags: android, drawing, line

I am drawing alphabet A using lines , if i gave the bounds for drawing A it will show complete 
A , But I want to show each line one by one means with some time delay between drawing of next line.

Tell me the idea for that.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [`Timer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) and [`TimerTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) with a fixed delay.

Answer (score 0):

Using animation you can get desired output. when 1st animation ends start next and so on.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html